# Why my code deployed in server behaves differently than my local instance, keeps throw GenericException when I have no problem testing it locally

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, cloud

I have been developing a Spring-boot REST api. The user will enter his password and my responsibility is to take the user entered password and try to connect with a system. If it doesn't work, then there are a set of default passwords that I can use from the database to establish the connection.
If a successful connection is established, then I return the response with system information along with the updated password.

Local:
In my machine, the api is working as expected. If I give wrong password, the api attempts a connection, after exception is thrown my api automatically retries with another password and keeps trying with all the passwords it has. If it succeeds I get success or else failure message.

In Server:
When I give correct password it works as expected.
When I give wrong password, I keep waiting and finally I get an exception in the UI with a 1000 status code and GenericException.

Here is what I have done so far....

1. I need to perform a few pre-requisite steps, I created a util class for completing these prerequisite steps.
   For example:

   ```
   //Collects default passwords that might work.
   public void fetchPasswordsFromDB(Request request){}

   //From the list of passwords from the database, retry and iterate to next passwords on failures
   public boolean setNextPassword (Request request){}
   ```
2. The above method will get the default passwords and set it to the request.
3. Then my request will enter another class that is responsible to establish connection with some system.
4. If we cannot connect to the system, then I try the connection with the next available password.
5. I keep iterating with retries until am exhausted of the passwords.
6. Finally, if I get connected, I will return a response back to the front end along with the response that I received.
7. I have put the retry mechanism in a catch block because my service throws an exception if the password is wrong so I catch the exception and retry from there.

   ```
   public class Utility {
   //Collects default passwords that might work.
   public void fetchPasswordsFromDB(Request request){}

   //From the list of passwords from the database, retry and iterate to next passwords on failures
   public boolean setNextPassword (Request request){}

   }
   public class SystemConnService {

   @Autowired
   private SystemConnectionHelper helper;

   @Autowired
   private Utility util;

   public ResponseEntity<ResponseObject> getConnection(Request request) {
         String connection = null;
         try {
             util.fetchpasswordsFromDB(request);
             connection = helper.connectSystems(request);
         } catch (CustomException ex) {
            return new ResponseEntity<ResponseObject>(new Object, FAILURE_REASON_CODE);
         }
     return ResponseEntity<ResponseObject>(new ObjectWithConnection, SUCCESS_REASON_CODE);

   }
   }

   @Component
   public class SystemConnectionHelper {
       private String connectSystems(Request request, boolean retry) throws CustomException {

       String systemResponse = null;
       try {
           systemResponse = executeRequest(request.getPassword);
       } catch (CustomException) {
           if(retry) {
               systemResonse = connectSystems(request, util.setNextPassword(request));
            }
         return systemResponse;
        }
   }
   ```

Expected is that my api must always return a response back to the UI regardless of the processing happening inside.

The UI gets this response: {"responseCode":1000,"responseText":"Generic.exception.message"}

**UPDATE:** Upon further testing, when I send two to three requests concurrently to my controller, after certain point of time, I get NullPointerException back to the UI with 500 reason code. I tried catching the NullPointerException every where in my code but I don't think it is being caught. Unfortunately am getting this from somewhere in backend, am unable to understand when and where it is being thrown.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli this is the response the ui gets {"responseCode":1000,"responseText":"Generic.exception.message"}

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Also in my local I was getting valid responses. The problem starts when its deployed in the UI and only during the retry scenarios. If the right password is entered, then UI gets valid response but when user enters wrong password, the UI gets this exception that I have shown you.

Comment: Please post the stack trace from the server otherwise we cannot help you

Comment: I checked the logs from the server multiple times, I do not see any stack trace. In fact I see that a valid response is being returned from the server and I also see a log where it is mentioned that the request has been completed successfully. The only response that I need from the UI side is the above exception and the connection getting stalled.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I noticed one notable difference between my local and server. The application is deployed on cloud and uses https and my local uses http. Do you think maybe the cloud server is configured to kill the persistent connection after a minute or so.

Comment: can you please post the stacktrace of the nullpointer?